# Member access into incomplete type 'CALayer'

Tags: ios, mapkit, calayer

For the code below :

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cellWidth, 240);
MKMapView *mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

mapView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;     
mapView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
```

I included MapKit,QuartzCore and CoreLocation Frameworks in addition.
For the last 2 lines, I am getting error : "Member access into incomplete type 'CALayer'"

Please tell me why I get this error and how to resolve this

EDIT: I got this error as I did not import Quartz.h, but i still dont understand why its saying incompleteness of CALayer type. Can anyone throw some light into depth of this.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you: `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`?

Comment: Oops.. its really bad on my side, I still make such mistakes. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

You should import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h  framework in your particular class or file.
I think you are not importing this framework in your particular file.

Comment: Yes, I didn't import, Actually I got biased with incompleteness of CALayer type, wondering what it might be