# Clang error: member access into incomplete type

Tags: c++11, namespaces, c++17, circular-dependency, forward-declaration

I have a very simple constellation from two classes "Id" and "IdValidator" and their corresponding interfaces. Bought classes depend on each other i.e. there is a circular dependency between bought of them. The problem with the circular dependency is solved by using a forward declaration. That all is compiling and linking just fine with clang i.e. git commit : [e4d4edafa924fad8902c52a10a2c0ebbd39907bf](https://github.com/courteous/visitor/tree/master) from branch master

Then I came to the need to split those two classes in different namespaces. All i did is without modifing the working version i created two directories and placed the corresponding class and it's interfaecs in the second directory. The changed the namepsaces and the corresponing includes.

I am able to execute "cmake ../", but when i run "make" I am facing the following error :

when I now compile the former working example i get the error

```
visitor/validator/IdValidator.cpp:36:23: error: member access into incomplete type 'std::__shared_ptr_access<IdInterface, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic, false, false>::element_type'
      (aka 'IdInterface')
                string name = entity->getName();
                                    ^
visitor/validator/IdValidatorInterface.h:12:7: note: forward declaration of 'IdInterface'
class IdInterface;
```

the 4 files of the non working version are in the branch split here i.e. commit [58345716e9b4a6062a470519690502b5fb80662a](https://github.com/courteous/visitor/tree/split)

here are the files in question:

IdValidator.h

```
#ifndef _ID_VALIDATOR_
#define _ID_VALIDATOR_

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <memory>
#include "../src/Id.h"
#include "IdValidatorInterface.h"

namespace validator
    {

    using Id = src::Id;
    using IdValidatorInterface = src::IdValidatorInterface;


    class IdValidator : public virtual IdValidatorInterface
        {

    public:

        IdValidator();
        virtual ~IdValidator();

        virtual bool isValid( shared_ptr<IdInterface> entity) override;

        vector<string> validate(shared_ptr<IdInterface> entity) override;

        };

    }


#endif
```

IdValidator.cpp

```
#include "IdValidator.h"
#include "../src/Id.h"
#include "../src/IdInterface.h"

using namespace std;

namespace validator
    {

    using Id = src::Id;

    IdValidator::IdValidator()
        {
        }

    bool IdValidator::isValid(shared_ptr<IdInterface> entity)
        {

        vector<string> listOfErros = validate(entity);

        if(listOfErros.empty() ){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }

        }

    vector<string> IdValidator::validate(shared_ptr<IdInterface> entity)
        {


        vector<string> stringList = vector<string>();

        // do some validation of the name
        string name = entity->getName();

        if (name == "BadName")
            {
            string error = "Error. id name is bad";
            stringList.push_back(error);
            return stringList;
            }

        return stringList;

        }
    }
```

IdValidatorInterface.h

```
#ifndef _ID_VALIDATOR_INTERFACE_
#define _ID_VALIDATOR_INTERFACE_

#include "BaseElementValidatorInterface.h"
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

class IdInterface;

namespace validator
    {


    class IdValidatorInterface : public virtual BaseElementValidatorInterface
        {

     public:
         IdValidatorInterface();
         virtual ~IdValidatorInterface();

         virtual bool isValid( shared_ptr<IdInterface> entity )  = 0;
         virtual vector<string> validate( shared_ptr<IdInterface> entity) = 0;

        };

    }

#endif
```

The compiler is basically complaining about the forward declaration "class IdInterface;" in the header file IdValidatorInterface.h.  I am not sure how to solve this thus asking for help here. 
Other articles suggest to include the file in question but that does not help in this situation i.e.

[member access into incomplete type ‘QScrollBar’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57948141/member-access-into-incomplete-type-qscrollbar)

[Member access into incomplete type 'CALayer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196105/member-access-into-incomplete-type-calayer)

Is this doable in c++ or do they have to be in the same namespace and same folder in order for this to work. I would really like to split those two.

I am using clang version 6.0.1  (emscripten 1.38.12 : 1.38.12)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

Comment: @rmawatson what would be the right way to declare the forward declaration. I have indeed tried to do something like "class src::IdInterface;" in the IdValidatorInterface.h file but that did not worked. Can you please elaborate a litte on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forward declare `IdInterface` at file scope. Looking at your [linked github repo](https://github.com/courteous/visitor/blob/58345716e9b4a6062a470519690502b5fb80662a/src/IdInterface.h#L12), `IdInterface` is defined in namespace `src`. `src::IdInterface != ::IdInterface` You have forward declared a type that is never defined.

Update your forward declaration to be in `namespace src` and it will likely fix your issue.

```
namespace src{
    class IdInterface;
}
namespace validator
{


class IdValidatorInterface : public virtual BaseElementValidatorInterface
    {

 public:
     IdValidatorInterface();
     virtual ~IdValidatorInterface();

     virtual bool isValid( shared_ptr<src::IdInterface> entity )  = 0;
     virtual vector<string> validate( shared_ptr<src::IdInterface> entity) = 0;

    };

}
```